# MATLAB - How do I automatically close the Import Wizard (command window)?

Tags: matlab

I am invoking the "uiimport" command within a program, opening the Import Wizard to display some data.  I would like to be able to automatically close the Wizard within a function (equivalent to "close(gcf)" for a figure), as opposed to having to click "Finish" or "Cancel" or whatever.  Is there a way to do this, or should I just find a different way to display the data?

TIA for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to automatically close the Wizard? Wouldn't it be better if the user were to decide when they're done inspecting the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would find a better way to show the data. `uiimport` is modal, so execution is suspended until it closes, so the script that started it cannot close it.